# "modify instance placement" grayed out - instance is stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a "cluster" placement group and stopped the instance but the "modify instance placement" is grayed out. The help text says:

> "The instance must be in the stopped state to modify its placement
>   properties. You cannot change the tenancy of an instance from default
>   to dedicated or host after you've launched it."

I am confused, I stopped it but maybe this means I have to actually create the instance in the placement group to begin with?

[image: AWS EC2 Instance Actions > Instance Settings > Grayed Out "Modify Instance Placement" menu item]

Comment: I was able to get instances in a placement group but only by specifying the placement group on instance launch creation. Even after this, the "Modify Instance Placement" is still grayed out. I wonder why that menu item is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move or remove the instance into a placement group by AWS web UI. This option is always greyed. I wonder when the same can be done by AWS CLI or SDK why it is not allowed on WEB UI.

Answer (score 0):

Before you move or remove the instance, the instance must be in the stopped state. You can move or remove an instance ONLY using the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html#change-instance-placement-group